# MS Access formula to derive minimum date

Tags: date, validation, ms-access, minimum

The below formula is giving error. Please help me solve my problem.

```
IIf((GetReportingDate()-[Final_Data]![Start Date])>(365*5*4),
  MIN([Final_Data]![Maturity Date] ,(DateAdd(“YYYY”,25, [Final_Data]![Start Date])),
IIf((GetReportingDate()-[Final_Data]![Start Date])>(365*5*3), 
  MIN([Final_Data]![Maturity Date] ,(DateAdd(“YYYY”,20, [Final_Data]![Start Date])),
IIf((GetReportingDate()-[Final_Data]![Start Date])>(365*5*2), 
  MIN([Final_Data]![Maturity Date] ,(Dateadd(“YYYY”,15, [Final_Data]![Start Date])),
IIf((GetReportingDate()-[Final_Data]![Start Date])>(365*5), 
  MIN([Final_Data]![Maturity Date],(Dateadd(“YYYY”,10, [Final_Data]![Start Date])),
IIf(([Final_Data]![Start Date]+365*5)<[Final_Data]![Maturity Date], 
  MIN([Final_Data]![Maturity Date],
    (Dateadd(“YYYY”,5, [Final_Data]![Start Date])),[Final_Data]![Maturity Date]))))),
  "Check")))
```

Getting Syntax error. Not getting minimum date

Apologies for long post. I am trying to derive re-pricing dates for loans stored in a table. The loan resets every 5 years and I do not have the loan previous re-set date info. I am trying to do it through Access Update Query Function. The above formula should address the below requirement.

1. If loan start date is more than 20 yrs from reporting date then Min(Start date+25 years, Loan Maturity Date)
2. If loan start date is more than 15 yrs from reporting date then Min(Start date+20 years, Loan Maturity Date)
3. If loan start date is more than 10 yrs from reporting date then Min(Start date+15 years, Loan Maturity Date)
4. If loan start date is more than 5 yrs from reporting date then Min(Start date+10 years, Loan Maturity Date)
5. If loan start date is less than 5 yrs from reporting date then Min(Start date+5 years, Loan Maturity Date)
6. If above conditions are not met, then Re-pricing date=Maturity Date

Comment: Is that supposed to be 3655 or some other number? Expressions this long are often better handled with a VBA custom function.

Comment: Expression really makes no sense. You have 5 independent IIf() conditionals calculating sequentially. That is not correct syntax. Calculation should be nested. Edit question to show sample data and desired output.

Comment: Is this expression in a query or a textbox? Exactly what is the error message? Edit your question with details.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Unfortunately, we had to convert an excel formula to Access and use it in Update Query function. Kindly let me know if there is any better of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You have an undefined MIN function
- Some closing parentheses were missing
- Smart quotes won't work. Use normal double-quotes: *"*
- Some years are leap years having 366 days
- Even with correct syntax, the expression appears as overly complicated

```vb
IIf(
    (GetReportingDate()-[Final_Data]![Start Date])>(365*5*4),
    MIN([Final_Data]![Maturity Date], DateAdd(“YYYY”,25, [Final_Data]![Start Date]),
    
IIf(
    (GetReportingDate()-[Final_Data]![Start Date])>(365*5*3), 
    MIN([Final_Data]![Maturity Date], DateAdd(“YYYY”,20, [Final_Data]![Start Date]),

IIf(
    (GetReportingDate()-[Final_Data]![Start Date])>(365*5*2), 
    MIN([Final_Data]![Maturity Date], Dateadd(“YYYY”,15, [Final_Data]![Start Date]),

IIf(
    (GetReportingDate()-[Final_Data]![Start Date])>(365*5),
    MIN([Final_Data]![Maturity Date], Dateadd(“YYYY”,10, [Final_Data]![Start Date]),

IIf(
    ([Final_Data]![Start Date]+365*5)<[Final_Data]![Maturity Date],
    MIN([Final_Data]![Maturity Date], Dateadd(“YYYY”,5, [Final_Data]![Start Date]),

[Final_Data]![Maturity Date]))))),"Check")))))
```

So, explain in plain English what you are trying to calculate, at best with some sample data and expected results.

A candidate for the MIN function could be this of mine:

```vb
' Returns the minimum date/time value of elements in a parameter array.
' If no elements of array Dates() are dates, the maximum value of Date is returned.
'
' Example:
'   DateMax(Null, "k", 0, -5, Date) -> 1899-12-25.
'
' 2016-02-14. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function DateMin( _
    ParamArray Dates() As Variant) _
    As Date

    Dim Element     As Variant
    Dim MinFound    As Date
      
    MinFound = MaxDateValue
    
    For Each Element In Dates()
        If IsDateExt(Element) Then
            If VarType(Element) <> vbDate Then
                Element = CDate(Element)
            End If
            If Element < MinFound Then
                MinFound = Element
            End If
        End If
    Next
    
    DateMin = MinFound
  
End Function
```

It uses a constant and a helper function. All of these can be found at my project at **GitHub**:

[VBA.Date](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Date)

**Addendum**:

I believe, an *exact* calculation taking leap years into account can be done on the fly (when needed) in VBA without updating anything using two of my functions, `DateMin` and `Age`, from my library linked to above:

```vb
MinimumDate = DateMin(DateAdd("yyyy", 5 * (1 + Age(StartDate, ReportingDate) \ 5), StartDate), MaturityDate)
```

Examples:

```vb
StartDate = #2015-12-12#
MaturityDate = #2025-12-31#
ReportingDate = #2022-12-14#
? DateMin(DateAdd("yyyy", 5 * (1 + Age(StartDate, Date) \ 5), StartDate), MaturityDate)
2025-12-12

StartDate = #2015-12-12#
MaturityDate = #2024-12-31#
ReportingDate = #2022-12-14#
? DateMin(DateAdd("yyyy", 5 * (1 + Age(StartDate, Date) \ 5), StartDate), MaturityDate)
2024-12-31
```

Comment: I see three args to `IIf`, but two to `MIN`. I think the user expects `Min` to return the lowest argument passed, which is of course not what that function does.

Comment: @ErikA: You are right. I've corrected the comments and syntax.

Comment: Thanks a lot for trying to help me. My apologies for making it complicated. I have added my requirement to the question. Can you help me now please

Comment: Yes. See extended answer, please.